# Find the maximum and minimum of a function (involving an trigonometric integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, optimization, definite-integrals

> Question: How can I find the maximum and minimum of this function, for a value of $\text{n}$?

$$\text{G}_\text{sc}\left(\text{n}\right)=\alpha\cdot\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)^2\tag1$$

Where $\alpha\space\wedge\space\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$

And, for $\theta$ we know that:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\theta\left(\text{n}\right)=\dots\tag2$$

Where $\text{A}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<\text{n}\le\text{A}$ and $\color{red}{\text{when you solve}}$ $\color{red}{\theta}$ $\color{red}{\text{we will get that}}$ $\color{red}{\theta}$ $\color{red}{\text{a function is of}}$ $\color{red}{\text{n}}$

---

**My work:**

In order to find the minumum and maximum:

$$\text{G}'_\text{sc}\left(\text{n}\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\text{n}}\left(\text{G}_\text{sc}\left(\text{n}\right)\right)=0\tag3$$

But I do not understand how to proceed.

Comment: where is $n$ in the rhs of (1)?

Comment: @Guangliang You have to read further, because $\theta$ is a function of $\text{n}$. See the red part!!

Comment: Is $n$ restricted to be an integer?

Comment: @Dr.MV No, $\text{n}$ does not have to be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$I(\theta) = \int_0^\theta \frac1{(1+\epsilon\cos x)^2}\,dx,$$ then$$\frac{dn}{d\theta} = \frac{A}{I(2\pi)(1+\epsilon\cos\theta)^2}.$$ The first order condition of $G' = 0$ becomes $$0 = \frac{dG}{dn} = \frac{dG}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dn} = -2\alpha\epsilon \frac{I(2\pi)}{A}\sin\theta(1+\epsilon\cos\theta)^3.$$  The zeros occurs at $\sin\theta = 0$ or $(1+\epsilon\cos\theta) = 0$.

Comment: Once you solved $dG/dn = 0$ for $\theta$, then $$n = \frac{A}{I(2\pi)}I(\theta).$$  Do you need closed form solutions or will numerical solutions work?

Comment: One obvious solution is $\theta = 2\pi$, which leads to $n  = A$.

Comment: From your Eq. (2),  the lhs is $\frac{n}{A}I(2\pi)$, the rhs is $I(\theta)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55020/discussion-between-guangliang-and-jan-eerland).